# Is there a word for Motherworld, similar to Motherland (Родина)?

Tags: перевод, существительные

родина means motherland, but I'm looking for the translation to a related word, "motherworld". This is similar to mother earth or mother nature.

Google translate does not even attempt a translation of it, but if I separate the two words, it gives me "Мать мир". Should I just put them together like "Матьмир"?

Comment: Природа-мать or Мать-природа

Comment: @RomanBezrabotny Thanks! Is there any difference between the two? Which one is more common, if any?

Comment: "Мать-Природа" - mother nature; "Мать-Земля" - mother earth. No direct analogue to "motherworld".

Comment: @DrZ214 they are identical

Comment: @user4419802 между motherland и родиной тоже нет прямой связи %). Вам смысл или формальный перевод)

Comment: @RomanBezrabotny Мать-Природа (Mother Nature), Мать-Земля(Mother Earth) тесно связаны с древнейшими языческими верованиями. А слово "Motherworld" представляется каким-то "новоделом". Конечно, всё зависит от контекста, но во многих случаях поставить между ними знак равенства будет никак не возможно.

Comment: @user4419802 Окей %) Какой ваш вариант?

Comment: @RomanBezrabotny Просто "Родина". В слове "Родина" нет никакого упоминания "land", так что оно подходит для "motherworld" ничуть не хуже, чем для "motherland". Единственная проблема возникнет, если нужно будет перевести оба эти слова в одном предложении.

Answer (score 7):

`Родина` means "place of birth". So it's valid word for both `Motherland` and `Motherworld`. Other valid translation of `Motherworld` is `родной мир`. If `Motherworld` is planet than `родная планета` is valid too.

Answer (score 3):

Possible translation - folk phraseologism **мать сыра земля** (mother earth) and Soviet idiom **Родина-мать** (homeland-mother)

Comment: *Родина-мать* was used idiomatically long before XX century.

Comment: @Quassnoi, в Нацкорпусе первое упоминание "Родина-мать" датируется 1918 г. http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F0%EE%E4%E8%ED%E0-%EC%E0%F2%FC&p=4

Comment: https://goo.gl/r317jS

Comment: @Quassnoi да, у Некрасова есть строчка "Родина мать! по равнинам твоим Я не езжал ещё с чувством таким!", но это отдельный образ, в отдельном не особо известном стихотворном произведении. Но именно идиомой "Родина-мать" стала после плаката Ираклия Тоидзе "Родина-мать зовёт" и ряда других агиток времён войны 1941-1945 гг. Прочие "матушка Русь", "матушка Россия" и т. п. - это отдельные языковые единицы, рождающие другие образы.

Comment: I quoted another poem, also by Nekrasov and probably his most renowned one, but nevermind. Do you really think it was not an established idiom to be used on a poster as emotionally charged as that? Have you tried putting a little more effort in your search?

Comment: @Quassnoi  про это же можно прочитать и в русской Википедии. Посмотрел в иностранных, там зачем-то пытаются подвязать к образу Родины-матери плакаты времён I Мировой, но изображение родины в виде женщины и Родина-мать - это разные образы, которые несут разную символическую нагрузку. "Русь матушка" и "Родина-мать" - это далеко не одно и тоже.

Comment: what I'm trying to say is that phrase, in that very form (*родина-мать*), was used by numerous authors long before the WWII and even long before the WWI, and not even necessarily in reference to Russia. It's a Russian idiom, not Soviet, that's all.

Comment: Фраза "родина-мать" до плаката Тоидзе, использоваться могла, но она не была идиомой.

Comment: nice circular reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

"Motherworld" is not an actual word in English - it is missing not just from Google Translate but from all major dictionaries. It is not possible to provide an accurate translation because there can be no consensus on the meaning of a made-up word.

I have seen "mother world" (two separate words) used in science fiction. If that was indeed the context you were looking for, I would say *планета происхождения*, or *планета-мать*, or *мать-планета*.

Answer (score 3):

How about **родные просторы** (set phrase) for **motherworld**?

*Простор* here would stand for 'vast area', or 'vast region'.

The plural form, *просторы*, would lend a poetic air.

And *родной* would cover for the 'mother' part.

Answer (score 1):

**Родина** means homeland. "Motherland" is an already needlessly ethnicised translation of a fairly generic term, and you're pretty much looking for something that doesn't exist outside of the English translation.

At any rate, there is no explicit "land" part in it. **-ина** is a place suffix — much like the **-ia** of **patria** or **Pennsylvania** — and you can't expect any natural language to have evolved a grammaticalized way to refer to "worlds" when humanity has been Earthbound for most of its history — and remains Earthbound in terms of permanent dwelling.

There may be ways to approximate "motherworld" in Russian but it will be an approximation of an English neologism which English speakers associate with Russia for a more or less random reason.

Answer (score 0):

Motherland is not close translation for Rodina. Rodina literally is "land of kin"/kinland. For Motherworld much possible closest translation will be rodnoy mir (Родной мир). Материнская планета can be used too.